# This is a formula in my text book,but I doubt the validity of it.

Tags: integration

[image]

This is a formula in my text book,but I doubt  the validity of it.If it is right,please give me a more detailed derivation.If it is wrong,please give me a right answer.

Comment: Why do you think *it* is wrong?

Comment: I think the third is wrong. There should be a constant,and how to get -1/n? How to compute the two integral in the third line?

Comment: Some parentheses seem to be missing in the last line.

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align}
a_n = \dfrac2{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \cos(nx) \ln\left(2 \sin\left(\dfrac{x}2 \right)\right)dx = \dfrac2{n \pi} \int_0^{\pi} \ln\left(2\sin\left(\dfrac{x}2\right)\right)d\left(\sin(nx)\right)
\end{align}
Now by integration by parts, we get that
\begin{align}
a_n & = \dfrac2{n \pi}\left(\left.\ln\left(2\sin\left(\dfrac{x}2\right)\right)\sin(nx)\right \vert_0^{\pi}-\int_0^{\pi} \sin(nx) \dfrac{\cos(x/2)}{2\sin(x/2)}dx\right)\\
& = \dfrac2{n \pi} \left(-\int_0^{\pi} \sin(nx) \dfrac{\cos(x/2)}{2\sin(x/2)}dx\right) = -\dfrac1{n \pi}\int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{\sin(nx) \cos(x)}{\sin(x/2)}dx\\
& = - \dfrac1{n \pi} \times \pi = -\dfrac1n
\end{align}
[where $$\int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{\sin(nx) \cos(x)}{\sin(x/2)}dx = \pi$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385306/it-is-an-easy-question-about-integral-but-i-need-your-help/385311#385311) Note that 
$$\ln\left(2\sin\left(\dfrac{x}2\right)\right)\sin(nx) =0 \text{ at }x = \pi \text{ since } \sin(n \pi) = 0 \text{ and } \ln(2 \sin(\pi/2)) = \ln(2)$$
Also,
$$\ln\left(2\sin\left(\dfrac{x}2\right)\right)\sin(nx) =0 \text{ as }x \to 0 \because \sin(n x) \sim nx \text{ and } \ln(2 \sin(x/2)) \sim \ln(x) \text{ as } x \to 0$$
and $\lim_{x \to 0} x \ln(x) = 0$.

Comment: You left out probably the hardest bit; also $\int_0^\pi d(\sin(nx)) looks wrong for several reasons.